# how to not display an element if it is undefined react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, jsx

There is the following problem. I have 6 divs on the page, which may or may not contain an image. Let's say I have 3 pictures in the array and these pictures should be displayed in a div, and the remaining 3 elements should be a div (for example, with a background) I roughly solved it, but if this element is not found in the array, then the application crashes. Crashing because some element is missing. In the console, an error like sixb[3] is undefined.
Item Display

```
<div className='blocksix all'>
    <img src={sixb[0].img} />
</div>
<div className='blocksix all'>
    <img src={sixb[1].img} />
</div>
<div className='blocksix all'>
    <img src={sixb[2].img} />
</div>
<div className='blocksix all'>
    <img src={sixb[3].img} />
</div>
<div className='blocksix all'>
    <img src={sixb[4].img} />
</div>
<div className='blocksix all'>
    <img src={sixb[5].img} />
</div>
```

Array of elements

```
let [sixb , setsixb] = useState([
        {img:"https://www.zonkpro.ru/zonk/assets/dice/mini/1.png"},
        {id:2,title:2, img:"https://www.zonkpro.ru/zonk/assets/dice/mini/2.png" , style: 'none'},
        {id:3,title:3, img:"https://www.zonkpro.ru/zonk/assets/dice/mini/3.png" , style: 'none'},
        {id:4,title:4, img:"https://www.zonkpro.ru/zonk/assets/dice/mini/4.png" , style: 'none'},
        {id:5,title:5, img:"https://www.zonkpro.ru/zonk/assets/dice/mini/5.png" , style: 'none'},
        {id:6,title:6, img:"https://www.zonkpro.ru/zonk/assets/dice/mini/6.png" , style: 'none'},   
 ])
```

No ideas yet how to solve

Comment: To avoid the error use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). And as the others answered, you should iterate through your array rather than copying the `divs` as many times as you may think it is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ternary operator and [optional chaining](https://kiranvj.com/blog/blog/optional-chaining-in-es7-and-support-in-react-js/)

```
<div className='blocksix all'>
    {sixb?.[1]?.img ? <img src={sixb[1].img} /> : <div className='some-background'>No image</div>}
</div>
```

Generic way of doing it -

```
{setsixb.map((item, index)=>{
   retrun <div className='blocksix all' key={index}>
             {item?.img ? <img src={item.img} /> : <div className='some-background'>No image</div>}
          </div>
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional rendering in this scenario.

```
<div className='blocksix all'>
    {sixb[0] && sixb[0].img && (<img src={sixb[0].img} />)}
</div>
```

Note:- Instead of writing the same `div` 6 times, just iterate over the array and display them.

```
{
  sixb.map((each,index) => {
      return (
             <div key={index} className='blocksix all'>
                {each && each.img && (<img src={each.img} />)}
             </div>
      )
  })
}
```

For `key`, I have used index as you don't have any unique property in an object. If you can make the `id` mandatory then use `id` as the key.

This way the code is more clean and readable.

Comment: I got 3 cubes, the other 3 should be divs

Comment: You can make use of the ternary operator as mentioned by @kiranvj

Comment: Oh sorry. I didn't understand much of the code. Now everything is fine, it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should try this,

```
<>
{sixb.map((element, index) => element?.img ? <div key={index} className="block-image"><img src="img" /></div> : <div key={index} className="no-image">No Image found</div>)}
</>
```